# Controlling likelyhood of randomly generated numbers

Tags: php, random, dice

If I wanted a random number between one and three I could do `$n = mt_rand(1,3)`.

There is a 33% chance that `$n` = 1, a 33% chance it's 2, and a 33% chance that it's 3.

What if I want to make it more difficult to get a 3 than a 1?

Say I want a 50% chance that a 1 is drawn, a 30% chance that a 2 is drawn and a 20% chance that a 3 is drawn?

I need a scalable solution as the possible range will vary between 1-3 and 1-100, but in general I'd like the lower numbers to be drawn more often than the higher ones.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is maths.

In your example the just chose a random number between 0 and 99.

Values returned between 0 to 49 - call it 1
Values returned between 50 - 69 - Call it 2
Values returned between 70 - 99 - Call it 3

Simple if statement will do this or populate an array for the distribution required

Answer (score 2):

There is a simple explanation of how you can use standard uniform random variable to produce random variable with a distribution similar to the one you want:

https://math.stackexchange.com/a/241543

Comment: +1 for pointing out that this question belongs on Math and not SO, but that is the furthest thing from a simple explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a 1 - 10 scale, you can use a simple if statement and have the numbers represent percentages. And just have each if statement set $n to a specific. Only downfall, it isn't universal.

```
$dummy = mt_rand(1,10);

// represents 50%
if ($dummy <= 5) {
    $n = 1;
} 
// represents 40%
if ($dummy >= 6 && $dummy <= 9) {
    $n = 2;
} else {
// represents 10%
    $n = 3;
}
```